# Tkinter problema al colocar icono imagen.ico

Tags: python, tkinter

Tratando de colocar icono a la ventan con Tkinter de Python, me da error.
¿Qué sucede?

**Código:**

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Hola mundo")
root.resizable(1,0)
root.iconbitmap('imagen.ico')
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
frame.config(width=480, height=520)
root.mainloop()
```

**Error:**

```
  File "C:\Miniconda3\envs\py37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1871, in wm_iconbitmap
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'iconbitmap', self._w, bitmap)
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "hola.ico" not defined
```

Un saludo.

Answer (score 5):

El error que presentas es por no encontrar la ruta definida del archivo.ico

> _tkinter.TclError: bitmap "hola.ico" not defined

debes colocar la ruta completa de tu ico desde la raiz de tu pc ejemplo
ventana.iconbitmap('C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\curso_p\pruebas\grupo.ico')